# c++ Compile error wiht visual studio 2017,differen file format

Tags: format, encode

IDE:visual studio 2017;
Language:c++;
I'm compiling a project,i set projects's 'character set' is unicode.the project imports different supplier's include files and libs,but these include files have some non-ASCII symbol and the files are different encode format,such as utf-8/gb2312/utf-8-bom, so when i compile, there appears many problems.

what should i do to solve the problem,thanks!